# Search ruby hash for empty value

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby hash like this

`h = {"a" => "1", "b" => "", "c" => "2"}`

Now I have a ruby function which evaluates this hash and returns true if it finds a key with an empty value. I have the following function which **always returns true even if all keys in the hash are not empty**

```
def hash_has_blank(hsh)  
  hsh.each do |k,v|  
    if v.empty?  
      return true  
    end  
  end
  return false
 end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This works fine for me. What's an example of a hash where you are seeing this problem (as your 'h' does have a blank value)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
def hash_has_blank hsh
    hsh.values.any? &:empty?
end
```

Or:

```
def hash_has_blank hsh
    hsh.values.any?{|i|i.empty?}
end
```

If you are using an old 1.8.x Ruby

Comment: You could do `hsh.each_value.any? &:empty?` in ruby >= 1.8.7 to avoid casting it into an array. But that might only matter for large hashes.

Comment: Warning: This will trigger on hash values which respond to the `empty?` method. Eg. `hash_has_blank({a: []}) == true`  which might not be the expected behaviour. @steenslag's suggestion can often be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks... that was helpful

Answer (score 8):

I hope you're ready to learn some ruby magic here. I wouldn't define such a function globally like you did. If it's an operation on a hash, than it should be an instance method on the Hash class you can do it like this:

```
class Hash
  def has_blank?
    self.reject{|k,v| !v.nil? || v.length > 0}.size > 0
  end
end
```

`reject` will return a new hash with all the empty strings, and than it will be checked how big this new hash is.

a possibly more efficient way (it shouldn't traverse the whole array):

```
class Hash
  def has_blank?
    self.values.any?{|v| v.nil? || v.length == 0}
  end
end
```

But this will still traverse the whole hash, if there is no empty value

I've changed the `empty?` to `!nil? || length >0` because I don't know how your `empty` method works.

Comment: Not very efficient as you are 1) traversing the whole hash, and 2) making another structure unnecessarily.

Comment: You're right, if update my answer. `include?` shouldn't traverse the whole hash, if it finds one occurrence of nil. But if you almost always have hashs which don't have empty values it shouldn't matter at all, because to return `false`, the function MUST ALWAYS traverse the whole hash.

Comment: Of course that any solution should traverse whole hash when there are no blanks.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to check if any of the values is an empty string you could do

```
h.has_value?('')
```

but your function seems to work fine.

Answer (score 4):

I'd consider refactoring your model domain. Obviously the hash represents something tangible. Why not make it an object? If the item can be completely represented by a hash, you may wish to subclass Hash. If it's more complicated, the hash can be an attribute.

Secondly, the reason for which you are checking blanks can be named to better reflect your domain. You haven't told us the "why", but let's assume that your Item is only valid if it doesn't have any blank values.

```
class MyItem < Hash

  def valid?
    !invalid?
  end

  def invalid?
    values.any?{|i| i.empty?}
  end
end
```

The point is, if you can establish a vocabulary that makes sense in your domain, your code will be cleaner and more understandable. Using a Hash is just a means to an end and you'd be better off using more descriptive, domain-specific terms.

Using the example above, you'd be able to do:

```
my_item = MyItem["a" => "1", "b" => "", "c" => "2"]

my_item.valid? #=> false
```

Comment: This is a cleaner way of doing it. jigfox's solution does it for me

Comment: If this was a throwaway script, then fine. But in a code review, I'd reject a monkey patch of a basic data structure in favor of proper object modeling.